# Angular velocity about arbitrary axis

Tags: rotations

Let $R$ be a Cartesian right-handed frame rotating with angular velocity $\omega_x$about its $x$-axis with respect to an inertial frame $F$, that is, $\mathbf{\omega}=[\omega_x \ 0 \ 0]^T$. let's define a vector $\mathbf{r}=[r_1 \ r_2 \ r_3]^T$ in $R$.

I want to find the angular velocity $\omega_r$, that is, the angular velocity of a point in $R$ about $\mathbf{r}$ which is induced by $\mathbf{\omega}$. I would think that the answer is the inner product $\omega_r=<\mathbf{\omega},\mathbf{r}>$. However, I did some simulations, and this seems to be wrong. I think that the problem is that $\mathbf{r}$ precesses about the $x$-axis. How do I integrate the precession of $\mathbf{r}$ into an expresseion for $\omega_r$?

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by the angular velocity of a point in $R$ about $\mathbf{r}$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net You may assume any point $p=\left(p_1,p_2,p_3\right) in $R$. If, for example, $p$ does not reside on the $x$-axis, it angular velocity about the $x$-axis is $\omega_x$. If $p$ does not reside on $\mathbf{r}$, what is the equeivalent angulare velocity of $p$ about $\mathbf{r}$. Please let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: You may assume any point $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ in $R$. If, for example, $p$ does not reside on the $x$−axis, its angular velocity about the $x$−axis, is $\omega_x$. If $p$ does not reside on $\mathbf{r}$, what is the equivalent angular velocity of $p$ about $\mathbf{r}$. Please let me know if this is clear enough.